# ¿Son off-topic las preguntas en cuanto al uso del español en el ámbito literario?

Tags: discusión, ámbito, off-topic

¿Es posible plantear preguntas si tenemos dudas en el ámbito literario referente al español?

Por ejemplo:

- ¿Qué quiso decir tal autor?
- Figurativa y filosóficamente, ¿qué significa esta frase?

¿O esto debería ser para el [Stack Exchange de literatura](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)? (lástima que solo esté en inglés).

Comment: No sé si lo filosófico quedaría bien. // Segundo la sugerencia de poner algunos ejemplos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El sitio [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com) tiene menos de un año (véase [en Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature)) y me suena que es el segundo intento de tener un sitio así. El anterior se cerró y los números actuales no son especialmente buenos. Con esto quiero decir que no sé hasta qué punto conviene contar especialmente con él (igual que [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/), que desgraciadamente languidece).

Dicho lo cual, ese sitio tiene una etiqueta específica para el tema: [spanish-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish-literature) con una veintena de preguntas que versan sobre obras de Vargas Llosa, Pablo Neruda, Jorge Luis Borges, etc. Creo que la descripción de la etiqueta es de bastante ayuda:

> For questions about Spanish literature: works of literature which were originally written in the Spanish language, whether from Spain, Latin America, or elsewhere.

En Spanish.SE hace cosa de un año hubo [un usuario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12202/jasonstack?tab=questions) que preguntó sobre expresiones, nombres y demás que aparecían en los libros en español que estaba leyendo. Se acogieron bien y no hubo conflicto con el off-topic.

Resumiendo:

- Las preguntas que versan sobre interpretaciones ligadas con biografías de autores y demás temas extra lingüísticos las vería off topic en Spanish.SE y aconsejaría preguntarlas en Literature.SE.
- Sin embargo, aquellas que versen sobre los usos de la lengua son perfectamente on topic en Spanish.SE.